# Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Find an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $f((a,b))$ is not open.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that $f((0,1))$ is not open. So I am arguing that if we consider the sequence $(1/n)_{n=2}^\infty$ which terms are within $(0,1)$, then we could find $x\in(0,1)$ such that $x<\sqrt{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$. So that we would have 
\begin{align}
\epsilon> x^2>\left\vert \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right\vert=\left\vert \frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}\right\vert=\left\vert \frac{1-(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right\vert=\vert f(x)-1\vert
\end{align}
and conclude that $1\in f((0,1))$ and similarly for $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $f((0,1))=[1,\frac{1}{2}]$. Does this argument necessarily imply $1,\frac{1}{2}\in f((0,1))$? If I am wrong, then how should I think about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Over $(0, 1)$, the function is strictly decreasing; the image will also be an open interval, in this case $(1/2, 1)$.

I would suggest graphing the function. The enemy of open maps are local extrema; try graphing the function and looking at open intervals containing $0$ to see what I mean.

Comment: This is informative. Thank you.

Comment: @TheLastCipher No worries!

Answer (score 2):

Since $f\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=\left(\frac12,1\right)$, you can't prove that $f\bigl((0,1)\bigr)$ is not open… since it *is* open!

**Hint:** $f\bigl((-1,1)\bigr)$ is not open. Just compute it.

Comment: now, this is just really embarrassing.

Comment: I don't doubt that. Now, learn from you errors and carry on.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2$ other really good answers but I think it would be good to point out your mistake:

At the step when you claim that $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ you are mistaken that $1$ is in the image of $f$ - this simply means that $1$ is a limit point of the image, i.e. there is a sequence which converges to $1$ consisting of points in the image. As this example shows, the limit point is not necessary in the set.